# How to parse a HTML response as json format using python?

Tags: python, html, json, database

I used python2 to make a request to RNAcentral database, and I read the response as JSON format by the use of this command: `response.json()`.

This let me read the data as a dictionary data type, so I used the corresponding syntax to obtain the data from cross references, which contained some links to other databases, but when I try to make the request for each link using the command mentioned above, I can't read it as JSON, because I can only obtain the response content as HTML.

So I need to know how to read make a request to each link from cross references and read it as JSON using python language.

Here is the code:

```
direcc = 'http://rnacentral.org/api/v1/rna/'+code+'/?flat=true.json'
resp = requests.get(direcc)
datos=resp.json()
d={}
links = []
for diccionario in datos['xrefs']['results']:
    if diccionario['taxid']==9606:
    base_datos=diccionario['database']
    for llave,valor in diccionario['accession'].iteritems():
        d[base_datos]={'url':diccionario['accession']['url'],
        'expert_db_url':diccionario['accession']['expert_db_url'],
        'source_url':diccionario['accession']['source_url']}
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    links.append(d[key]['expert_db_url'])
for item in links:
    response = requests.get(item)
    r = response.json()
```

And this is the error I get: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the `requests` library?

Comment: You should, please, show us the code that you wrote to make a request for one of those links so that we can advise you.

Comment: Yes, I used the requests library. I've already posted the code in the question.

Comment: Your `for llave,valor in diccionario['accession'].iteritems():` is useless as you overwrite `d[base_datos]=` again and again. Second, for me `d[key]['expert_db_url']` is Empty?